# Does facebook pixel track users when they are redirected to target blank pages?

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, facebook-pixel

i am putting facebook pixel in the footer which is in all my website pages , when the customer purchases a product , they will be redirected to a thank you page using Javascript , does facebook pixel can track the users in this way even if they are redirected using target blank ?

```
if(true){ ?>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    window.open(
  'https://thankYouPage',
  '_blank' 
);
} 

</script>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as your redirect target page is still on the same domain and has the FB Pixel code contained then it'll track seamlessly through the journey as the FB cookies will still be present for the session regardless of tabs/windows.